# PowerShell problem with array and grouping objects

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops, foreach, server

I am having problems to group an array of objects by Environment. The following script show three environments with servers in each one. Now, I am trying to loop those objects by groups but getting errors with the Environment names. The following is my sample logic:

```
$array = @(("DEVELOPMENT", ("SRV1")), ("QA", ("SRV2", "SRV3")), ("PRODUCTION", ("SRV4", "SRV5")))

ForEach ($system in $array) {
    $envName = $array[0]
    ForEach ($hostname in $system[1]) {
        Write-Host ("Result for " + $hostname + " in " + $envName)
    }
}
```

The variable name $envName always returns the same wrong result.

```
[0]:"DEVELOPMENT"
[1]:"SRV1"
```

How can I group and loop $array[0] and $system[1] in the following way?

```
DEVELOPMENT = SRV1
QA          = SRV2, SRV3
PRODUCTION = SRV4, SRV5
```

Comment: Looks like a typo. Instead of `$envName = $array[0]` you should write `$envName = $system[0]`.

Comment: You are right - i have just realised it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to create an object array instead of an embedded string array.

```
class Server
{
    [string]$Environment
    [string]$ServerName
}


$Development = @("SRV1")
$Qa = @("SRV2", "SRV3")
$Production = @("SRV4", "SRV5")

$Array = @()

foreach ($System in $Development)
{
    $Server = [Server]::new()
    $Server.ServerName = $System
    $Server.Environment = "Development"
    $Array += $Server
}

foreach ($System in $Qa)
{
    $Server = [Server]::new()
    $Server.ServerName = $System
    $Server.Environment = "QA"
    $Array += $Server
}

foreach ($System in $Production)
{
    $Server = [Server]::new()
    $Server.ServerName = $System
    $Server.Environment = "Production"
    $Array += $Server
}

foreach ($System in $Array)
{
    Write-Host "Result for $($System.ServerName) in $($System.Environment)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the comments

```
"Instead of $envName = $array[0] you should write $envName = $system[0]"
```